# Call a jQuery.ajax action function from inside a class

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

```
function submit_onClick() {
    var addValue = jQuery("#billing_address_1").val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {'action':'distance_calculation', addValue:addValue}
    }).done(function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

this works fine until  I dont place distance_calculation inside any class.
 how can i call a function if its inside any class for example, if distance_calculation function is inside any class called "distance" then how to call this in action .

Comment: In your question, distance_calculation is a string literal, not a function.

Comment: because of quotes around it ?

Comment: yes because of it. What do you want 'distance_calculation' to be?

Comment: i want it to be function

Comment: If you want it to be a function then you have to use `'action': distance_calculation()`

Comment: even if do so, if `distance_calculation` is inside another function as a closure then it will not be accessable

Comment: its inside another class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the the ajax request like so

```
function submit_onClick() {
    var addValue = jQuery("#billing_address_1").val();
        jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?method=distance_calculation&addValue=addValue"
            }).done(function(data) {
                alert(data);
            });
}
```

Then in your PHP file add

```
if(strcmp($_POST["method"],"distance_calculation")){
     $class->distance_calculation($_POST["addValue"]);
}
```

Comment: will it work if distance_calculation method is inside any class and not directly inside php file ?

Comment: You just have to have a means of accessing the function somewhere **inside** the .php file you post back too.